# debian lenny : problem modifying static ip

Tags: linux, debian, interface

i'm trying to change a static ip assigned to a debian VM. I modified the ***/etc/network/interfaces*** file but my debian doesn't seem to like the new settings

currently the machine's ip is set to 192.168.1.136
and i want the machine's ip to be set to 192.168.1.8

here's my modified ***/etc/network/interfaces* :**

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

allow-hotplug eth0

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.1.8
gateway 192.168.1.1
netmask 255.255.255.0
```

Comment: The configuration seems OK. Did you restart your network using `sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart`?

Answer (score 1):

The Debian way to reloading the networking configuration is :

`/etc/init.d/networking restart` as root

Comment: except, the script says "force-reload|restart) \n Running $0 $1 is deprecated because it may not enable again some interfaces"

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
ifdown eth0 ; ifup eth0
```

to "reload" network config. Or just reboot machine. Also, Debian (and a lot of other distros) by default "binds" given interface MAC to interface name using udev (/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules) so if you changed MAC of machine correct interface will be eth1 (to "undo it", remove that udev file)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the interface name is not eth0 anymore? Try the following to learn about your interface names:

```
# ifconfig | grep ^eth
```

If necessary, change the configuration in /etc/networking/interfaces and restart network:

```
# /etc/init.d/networking restart
```

(as root)